# limit of the sum $ \sum_{i=1}^N a_N(i) $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I have that strange sum:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N a_N(i)
$$ 
for which I want to compute the limit as $N\to \infty$, except that I have as an additional condition $\lim_{N\to \infty}a_N(i)=0$.

I have that bizzare intuition that this serie should converge to zero except that I can't figure how ? or maybe my intuition is wrong !! What do you think ?

Comment: Your notation is kind of strange.  $a_N(i)$ is a function of both $N$ and $i$?

Comment: yes, it's a function that depends on both $i$ and $N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series need not converge to zero, if all you know is that $\lim_{N\to\infty}a_N(i)=0$. Take, for instance, the degenerate case
$$
a_N(i) = \frac1N,\qquad\text{for all $i=1,\ldots N$}.
$$
Then $\sum_{i=1}^N a_N(i)$ is equal to $1$ for every $N$.

Comment: yes you're right ! I've missed that :p thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make this conclusion you need additional conditions.  A popular one  is that there is some sequence $b_i \ge 0$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty b_i < \infty$ and $|a_N(i)| \le b_i$ for all $i$ and $N$.

Comment: so under this condition I can conclude that the limit of $\sum_{i=1}^N a_N(i)$ is zero as $N\to \infty$ ? if it's okay can you give a reference as I want to see the proof :)

Comment: It's not hard to prove on your own.  You need to put two results together: first, if $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} |a_i|$ converges, then so does $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i$.

Second, if $0 \leq a_i \leq b_i$ for all $i$, and if $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} b_i$ converges, then so does $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i$.  This is because $$0 \leq \sum\limits_{i=1}^N a_i \leq \sum\limits_{i=1}^N b_i \leq \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} b_i < \infty$$  for all $N$. Now, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^N a_i$ is a bounded increasing sequence, so it must converge.

Comment: It's a special case of the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you !